# Asset file is missing when deploying app to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

[Assets is a folder in my local computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAxzD.png)

[No such folder exists when I deploy the app to heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW0A1.png)

Comment: Are those files committed?

Comment: @Chris yes they are

Comment: your app running or not, it throws any error

Comment: you can not see the backend source code in dev tools or maybe anywhere.

Comment: @Tushar the error it gives is that it can't load the images that are in my asset files

Comment: @Tushar the assets folder should be with the client too right?

Comment: make image directory in the public directory and move all into the image directory, give the path according to it, I hope it can help

Comment: @Tushar image directory is in the public directory

Comment: yes make an image folder in public directory

Comment: Are you _absolutely sure_ they're committed? Are you pushing the correct branch? I'm seeing other differences there too, like `enemyPlayers.js` which is in your local screenshot but not your remote one.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.